# Producing a diagram showing relations between sets?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

I'm just starting to use Latex and I was wondering if it's possible to produce a graphic like the following.

[image: Relations]

It seems like I would have to start with something like a table and then somehow add in the arrows. Any pointers to produce something like this would appreciated.

Comment: Somehow related: [Create a command to draw edges in a bipartite graph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54342/13304).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); you place some nodes and then draw the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mydot/.style={
  circle,
  fill,
  inner sep=2pt
},
>=latex,
shorten >= 3pt,
shorten <= 3pt
]
\node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {}; 
\node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {}; 
\node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {}; 
\node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

\node[mydot,right=2cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {}; 
\node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {}; 
\node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {}; 
\node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {}; 

\path[->] (a1) edge (b1)
  edge (b2)
  edge (b3)
  edge (b4);
\path[->] (a2) edge (b3)
  edge (b4);
\path[->] (a3) edge (b1)
  edge (b3);
\path[->] (a4) edge (b2) 
  edge (b4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more "traditional" approach using the `picture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{.5in}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(3,4)
\linethickness{1pt}

\multiput(0,0)(0,1){4}{$\bullet$}
\multiput(2,0)(0,1){4}{$\bullet$}

\put(-0.2,0){4}
\put(-0.2,1){3}
\put(-0.2,2){2}
\put(-0.2,3){1}

\put(2.2,0){4}
\put(2.2,1){3}
\put(2.2,2){2}
\put(2.2,3){1}

\put(0.2,0.1){\vector(2,1){1.8}}
\put(0.2,0.1){\vector(1,1){1.8}}
\put(0.2,0.1){\vector(1,0){1.8}}
\put(0.2,1.1){\vector(1,0){1.8}}
\put(0.2,2.1){\vector(2,1){1.8}}
\put(0.2,2.1){\vector(1,0){1.8}}
\put(0.2,2.1){\vector(1,-1){1.8}}
\put(0.2,3){\vector(1,-1){1.8}}
\put(0.2,3.1){\vector(1,0){1.8}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!
Another quick question though, what does this part
`>=latex,
shorten >= 3pt,
shorten <= 3pt
do?`

Comment: @user3254763 those options shorten the start (`shorten <= 3pt`) and end (`shorten >= 3pt`) of the arrows so they don't touch the filled circles.

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks just for fun as usual.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\begin{document}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1,colsep=2,mnode=dot]
[name=l1]   & [name=r1]\\
[name=l2]   & [name=r2]\\
[name=l3]   & [name=r3]\\
[name=l4]   & [name=r4]
\end{psmatrix}
\multido{\i=1+1}{4}{\uput[180](l\i){\i}\uput[0](r\i){\i}}
\psset{nodesep=3pt,arrows=->}
\ncline{l1}{r1}
\ncline{l1}{r2}
\ncline{l2}{r4}
% just add your own connecting lines here
\end{document}
```

[image]